# Deleted files on external disc do not increase disc space

Tags: disk-space

I have deleted view files on an external ssd disk Samsung T7 Shield 1TB, but disc space did not increased. It means that if disc space has for example 300 MB avaiable space and I am deleting file which has 100 MB, I  have still 300 MB, not 400 MB. Files are disapearing from the list of files. Files there are not in Trash bin either.
Besides of photo files on the same disc I have time machine backups.

Disk is connected to MacBook pro (Retina, 13-inch, Mid 2014);
Mac OS Big Sur 11.7.6.

Do you have any idea how to fix it, how to delete files in order to get additional space on disc ?

Comment: Why would files on a disk be related to free memory (RAM) on your computer?  Memory is used when things are loaded into it (like opening a file). What problem are you trying to solve.  Also, when you update your post with an [edit], be sure to inclue your Mac model, your OS and ehat you’re doing so we can get a clear picture.

Comment: Could the files be still open by some application? Space may only be reclaimed after files are no longer referenced by anything in the system.

Comment: Please also include the output from `diskutil list` issued on the terminal command line. If you have Time Machine backups on the same disk, I hope they are in a separate volume. As disk space is shared by APFS volumes in a container you may be mistaking an increase in TM usage for unreleased free space by your non-TM files.

Comment: External drive has no separate volume.

Comment: I am not sure if this is what you wanted to see:

Comment: I can't upload the photo ;(